# Why isn't my JavaScript function able to access global-scope functions/variables defined in my other .js files?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a script like that:

```
NS.load = function(src) {
    var script = document.createElement("script").setAttribute("src", src);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

It loads files but I can't reach functions and variables defiened in other files.

```
//js/main.js
var qux = {name: "name"};
NS.load("js/foo.js");

//js/foo.js
alert(qux.name); //undefined variable
```

But if I define qux like this:

```
window.qux = {name: "name"};
```

I can reach qux variable in other modules. As far as I know all globals are already a member of window object. So why I have to define variables like this. Could you offer another method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you tried to shortcut your code by calling `createElement` and `setAttribute`  all on 1 line, but `setAttribute` doesn't return anything, so you can't go calling `appendChild` on it's return value, because there is none.This will fix it:

```
NS.load = function(src) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", src)
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

**Edit:**

What sort of environment are you running your code in?  Is something happening cross-site or are you defining qux inside of another function?  The following works for me, running the files via http://localhost/test.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        load = function(src) {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.setAttribute("src", src);
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        }
        var qux = {name: "name"};
        load("foo.js");
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

foo.js:

```
alert(qux.name);
```

I get an alert with "name" when the page loads.

Comment: Thanks Langdon. Actually original code is same with yours. I cut it for brevity. But I didn't know setAttribute() return value. It is good to learn this.

Comment: Your code is working. "What sort of environment are you running your code in?" This is the question and answer. Now I got it. Actually my loader code is in jQuery's ready method, thereby I have to bind variables to window object to reach other modules.
Thanks Langdon.